# virtualenvwrapper: where is virtualenv info stored?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I regularly use `setvirtualenvproject /path/to/my/project/` to set the root/base directory of my virtual env. This is useful when switching to a virtual env using `workon myenv`.

I was wondering though, if this path is available anywhere else?

In my case, I want to run a pre-push hook in git, and need to get the full path to some of my files.
e.g. something like this in my pre-push hook:
`do_something $VIRTUALENV_PROJECT/my/important/file.txt`

Is there any way I can retrieve this 'virtualenvproject' info, or where is it stored?

I've tried looking in `env`, the `.virtualenvs` dir and every other place I can think of, but I just can't find where the info's stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems like there were no quick takers... I ended up looking at the virtualenvwrapper.sh [source](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/f0f0077888c00aa1f3cc810c3de7767a8441a679/virtualenvwrapper.sh?at=master#cl-960), which shows that the path is dumped into `$venv/$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME`.

A simple `echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME` will show you the name for your project settings (default is `.project`)
The fact that it's hidden is what was killing me.

So now I know this, I can do a simple:

`cat $VIRTUAL_ENV/$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME` to get the setting. Simple!